Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction after internet connection restore
I have a long for loop (5k loops) each loop make an operation to database through
if(!runnedPedidosToBulkOrCronjobClientesService.checkIsRunned(pedido.getId())){
                            return;
 }

The checkIsRunned method is that one will look up over the database it's:
public Boolean checkIsRunned(Integer id_pedido){
    return runnedPedidosToBulkOrCronjobClientesRepository.findById(id_pedido).isEmpty();
}

Where runnedPedidosToBulkOrCronjobClientesRepository is a injected instance from a JbaRepository
@Repository
public interface RunnedPedidosToBulkOrCronjobClientesRepository extends JpaRepository<RunnedPedidosToBulkOrCronjobClientesEntidade,Integer> {
}

This for loop is triggered by a HTTP request, and it returns no exception in each loop, but if internet goes down and it's restored, even after it's restores each for loop will EVER throw a exception, I need to restart the loop to get the things back to work
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction

The part of for loop which gets me this exception is:
if(!runnedPedidosToBulkOrCronjobClientesService.checkIsRunned(pedido.getId())){
                            return;
 }

The exceptions is:
 Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction

with detail:
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed

I suspect the repository gets bugged state after internet is restored, probably instantiate this repository would resolve the problem but I still would like to use dependency injection, I need a solution can hold it without reseting for loop in a internet loss.
Below is my application.properties:
spring.datasource.url=scrt
spring.datasource.username=scrt
spring.datasource.password=scrt
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
api.security.token.secret=scrt
api.paginacao-size=50
server.port=9999

app.varejo-token=scrt


spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000

PS: I configured all database connection by application.properties and by JbaRepository and @Entity

Specify a minimum and maximum of connections with different sizes and enable connection validation.

@M.Deinum it didn't work, if I call a endpoint which uses this repository it returns me the data even after net restore, but the for loop will get bugged for remaining loops, I think it's regards a connection which was lost

THen you haven't configured it correctly. Make sure you enable checking while idle and on acquire as well. This will constantly validate connections and create new ones if a connect isn't valid. Don't use connection-test-query not needed with JDBC4 also you have't set min-idle to something else which mean both are 10 hence no checking will be done.

spring.datasource.testOnBorrow=true
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=5000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000

I call an endpoint which starts this loop if the loop is killed and I call the endpoint again (without reseting the server) even after internet down and restore I can do records in database, but if I don't kill the loop all remaing loops after internet is restored get cursed , I think it's because my loop regards in memory a dependency which got an invalid state in that space, because spring context is not invalid for new requests but the spring context in the moment the loop started got invalidated and I don't know how to deal with that

I had the exact same issue. After each network outage, the JDBC connection pool would contains connection that is dead and non recoverable (java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed).
You are probably using the default connection pool manager HikariCP. This case is documented here
https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Rapid-Recovery#unacknowledged-tcp
Although it is documented by HikariCP, the same solution would apply for other connection pool manager.
Just update your jdbc connection string with the appropriate parameter (Link for each DB in their documentation). We were using SQL Server, we added jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;databaseName=DB;socketTimeout=360000
and the app started to recover by itself.

unfortunely it didnt solve, the problem is the connection station in for loop, if internet is restored other endpoints would return me data from DB, unlike that for loop which was and is running between internet down an up

i used jdbc:mysql://server:port/CRMDatabase?socketTimeout=30000

I don't know how but the following was solved the problem:
public void myMethod(){//long 5k of for loops which depends from database}

instead calling classInstance.myMethod()
I used
Callable<Void> task = () -> {
    classInstance.myMethod();
    return null;
};

ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);//instanciar aqui evita concorrencia entre as chamadas

Future<Void> future = executorService.submit(task);

Now when the internet gets down and so up the database connection is restaured.
